# Не удается изменить артибут тега средствами php

Tags: php, html, dom

Имеется html код на одной из страниц проекта:

```
                            <select name="genre" id="genre" required>
                                <option value="Джаз">Джаз</option>
                                <option value="Классика">Классика</option>
                                <option value="Модерн">Модерн</option>
                                <option value="Народный">Народный</option>
                                <option value="Восточный">Восточный</option>
                            </select>
```

Нужно средствами php присвоить одному из тегов option атрибут selected.

```
$genre = $event['genre']; // получаем название жанра из бд


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('events/edit.php');
$options = $dom->getElementsByTagName('option');
foreach ($options as $option) {
    if ($option->nodeValue === $genre) {
        $option->setAttribute('selected', '');
        echo $dom->saveHTML($option);
    }
}
```

ошибок никаких не выскакивает, документ по команде loadHTMLFile грузится. Но ничего не происходит.

Атрибуту option присваивается selected только если указать

```
      echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Но тогда обновляется вся страница и сбрасывается сессия php, а этого хочу избежать

Comment: Что за бред вообще. Почему в edit.php нельзя написать что-то типа `<option value="Джаз"<?=$genre === 'Джаз' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Джаз</option>`

Comment: можно, если не атрибутов списка немного. А если их 100?

Comment: А если их 100 - то надо их поместить в массив, и затем циклом этот массив обойти. И в цикле будет одно действие: `<option value="<?=$currentGenre?>"<?=$genre === $currentGenre ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?=$currentGenre?></option>`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
$event['genre'] = 'Модерн'; // temp string

$genre = $event['genre']; // получаем название жанра из бд

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('events/edit.php');
$selects = $dom->getElementsByTagName('select');
foreach ($selects as $select) {
    $options = $dom->getElementsByTagName('option');
    foreach ($options as $option) {
        if ($option->nodeValue == $genre) {
            $option->setAttribute('selected', '');
        }
    }
    echo $dom->saveHTML($select);
}
```

Upd: в `edit.php` это

```
<select name="genre" id="genre" required>
    <option value="Джаз">Джаз</option>
    <option value="Классика">Классика</option>
    <option value="Модерн">Модерн</option>
    <option value="Народный">Народный</option>
    <option value="Восточный">Восточный</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Нет не сработало как надо. Я в качестве выхода записал значение $dom->saveHTML($select) в переменную и вставил уже ее в html документ вместо старого списка. Костыли, но другого выхода нет

Comment: Обновил ответ. Думал у вас так же.